# how to add multiple events in google calendar android Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile, android-listview

For calendar, we want to show multiple events in calendar view on android.
Events coming from the API
`https://myfarmapp1.herokuapp.com/api/v1/upcoming/actions/dates?userId=61efd161be38db6f4ab23fe7`.
Using the above API I want to show multiple events on Calendar view.
What is the Problem?
When we set event date on calendar its show latest event on the calendar and previous events are not showing.

```
val call: Call<com.android.farmist.model.dateCalender.Date> =
   

                 Api_Controller().getInstacne().getDates(userId)
                call.enqueue(object : 
        Callback<com.android.farmist.model.dateCalender.Date> {

                    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
                    override fun onResponse(
                        call: Call<com.android.farmist.model.dateCalender.Date>,
                        response: Response<com.android.farmist.model.dateCalender.Date>
                    )
                    {

                        val respo = response.body()
                        if (respo ?.allDates!= null) {


                            for (i in respo.allDates)
                            {

                                val y = i.value.year
                                val m = i.value.day
                                val d = i.value.date

                                val  events: MutableList<EventDay> = ArrayList()
                                val  calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
                                val  calendar2=Calendar.getInstance()
                                val  calendar3 = Calendar.getInstance()

                               calendar.set(y,m-1,d)
//                                Toast.makeText(requireActivity(),
//                                    "${calendar2}",
//                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                calendar2.set(y,m-1,d-1)
                                calendar3.set(y,m-1,d-2)

                               events.add(EventDay(calendar, R.drawable.dot))
                                Log.d("editDate","${(y ).toString() + (m-1 ).toString() + (d ).toString()}")
                                events.add(EventDay(calendar2, R.drawable.dot))
                                events.add(EventDay(calendar3, R.drawable.dot))
                                binding.calendar.setEvents(events)
                            }
                        }
                      }

                    override fun onFailure(
                        call: Call<com.android.farmist.model.dateCalender.Date>,
                        t: Throwable
                    ) {
                        Log.d("userId", t.toString())


                    }
                })
```

Answer (score 1):

The Google Calendar API allows to set multiple events e.g. by starting a list of intents.

```
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivities

startActivities(context, arrayOf(intent, intent2))
```

Likewise, startActivity starts a single intent

```
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity

startActivity(context, intent, null)
```

As described in the [Android Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider), an intent itself can look as follows.

```
import android.content.Intent

val startMillis: Long = Calendar.getInstance().run {
    set(2012, 0, 19, 7, 30)
    timeInMillis
}
val endMillis: Long = Calendar.getInstance().run {
    set(2012, 0, 19, 8, 30)
    timeInMillis
}
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
        .setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI)
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, startMillis)
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endMillis)
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Yoga")
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group class")
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "The gym")
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY, CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY)
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I am passing an array of 9 intents, only the first one is visible and gets created.